# Insert an auto increment id to another column in same table and prepend a character without updating it on seperate query

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I need to insert the auto incremented 'invoice_id' to the second column 'invoice_code' and prepend the character 'z' to it. Is there a way to do it without updating it on seperate query?

Here's what i expect to see in my columns:

```
---------------------------------------------
| invoice_id | invoice_code | invoice_value |
---------------------------------------------
|           1|            z1| sample value1 |
|           2|            z2| sample value2 |
|           3|            z3| sample value3 |
---------------------------------------------
```

Here's my query so far:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO invoices () VALUES(null,
                                        'z'.invoice_id,
                                        'sample value'.invoice_id
                                        )";
```

Comment: I think maybe you have to use multiple queries. And you can get the last inserted id by LAST_INSERT_ID() which detail you can get at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html So first inset the record, second retrieve the last inserted id, and third  is update the last inserted record.

Answer (score 0):

try something like,

```
$count = 1;
while ($count <= 3) {
    $query .= "INSERT INTO invoices ("invoice_code", "invoice_value") VALUES('z'.$count, 'sample value'.$count);";
    $count++;
}
```

Sorry edited, wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by using mysqli's function [mysqli_insert_id($conn)](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'database');
$query      = "INSERT INTO invoices (invoice_value) VALUES('sample')";

// Creates new record
mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Then fetch last inserted id

```
// Fetches newly inserted id
$id  = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
```

Then update the existing row

```
$update = "UPDATE invoices SET invoice_code='z".$id."' WHERE invoice_id = ". $id;

// Updates the existing record with autoincrement id 
mysqli_query($connection, $update);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what is the next auto increment id for this table.

I will do this

```
$query = "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'table_name' AND table_schema = DATABASE( )";
```